# CSS3 background: repeating-linear-gradient

Tags: html, css, background, linear-gradients

A couple of days ago I read this article: http://tutorialzine.com/2013/10/12-awesome-css3-features-you-can-finally-use/

and found about the new CSS3 syntax [`repeating-linear-gradient`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/repeating-linear-gradient).

So far it only works in FireFox, even though I use prefixes.

```
background: #000;
background-image: -webkit-repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, black, black, #2a2a2a 6px, #2a2a2a 6px);
background-image: -moz-repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, black, black, #2a2a2a 6px, #2a2a2a 6px);
background-image: -ms-repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, black, black, #2a2a2a 6px, #2a2a2a 6px);
background-image: -o-repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, black, black, #2a2a2a 6px, #2a2a2a 6px);
background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, black, black, #2a2a2a 6px, #2a2a2a 6px);
```

I have the latest versions of Google Chrome(`Version 30.0.1599.101 m`) and IE(`v9.0.8112.16421`). I cannot update IE to a higher version, because of some company policies.

Am I doing something wrong?

[This is my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ErmCr/)

Comment: According to http://caniuse.com/css-repeating-gradients this is supported since 10.0 (-webkit-) and 26.0 (without prefix) respectively.

Comment: That is strange, because it doesn't work. I also cleared the complete cache from the browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example does work here in Firefox (20.0) and Chromium (25.0.1364.160). I adapted the example from [MDN - repeating-linear-gradient](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/repeating-linear-gradient). I only added a width and height

```
#grad3 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4aZqg/3/)

When you change one of the black colors, you will see the pattern better, see modified [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4aZqg/4/).

Comment: The JSFiddle works in Google Chrome, but the same code in my website does not. [This is my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ErmCr/)

Comment: Then there's something else in your website, which prevents the gradient from working. Look into the console for any error message.

Comment: Nope I got no errors. Does this fiddle work in your Google Chrome?

Comment: Yes, it does. I thought, the JSFiddle works in your Chrome too?

Comment: I posted a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ErmCr/) of my Code and this does not work.

Comment: As I said, it does work. It is hardly visible though (black, black). When you change the colors (i.e. lime, black), you will see it far better, see http://jsfiddle.net/ErmCr/2/

Answer (score 0):

for IE 8,10 can use:

```
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #1e5799 0%,#2989d8 50%,#207cca 51%,#7db9e8 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #1e5799 0%,#2989d8 50%,#207cca 51%,#7db9e8 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#1e5799', endColorstr='#7db9e8',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-8 */
```

IE9 not support CSS Gradiant,
http://css3wizardry.com/2010/10/29/css-gradients-for-ie9/
i recommend ussing -pie-gradiant for the issue in IE9:
http://css3pie.com/documentation/supported-css3-features/

also you can use http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/  for better result,